# How can I receive a void parameter in function definition, C or C++?

Tags: c++, c

How can I receive in a function definition when the one of the parameter in function call is `void`?

The scenario is that one of my projects, in a function call one of the parameters is `void`. That section I could not change.
I can change only the function declaration or the function definition, but I still confused what I need to change.

Please help

Below code is not a executable one:

for ex:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(void, int a) {
    printf("%d", a);
}

int main() {
    test(void, 32);
}
```

Comment: `void test(void,int a){}` is invalid in both C and C++, you'll need to find a really exotic compiler to accept it.

Comment: Are you sure the paremeter isn't supposed to be `void*`?

Comment: "_in a function call one of the parameter is void_" Are you sure that the code was `test(void);`?

Comment: If this were allowed, there wouldn't be much of a point since the type `void` has no values. (In C++, maybe a few weird template tricks would become possible, I suppose.)

Answer (score 4):

You can't. That is not valid C:

```
<source>:2:11: error: 'void' must be the only parameter
    2 | void test(void,int a)
      |           ^~~~
```

Same goes for C++:

```
<source>:2:11: error: invalid use of type 'void' in parameter declaration
    2 | void test(void,int a)
      |           ^~~~
```

The only valid use of void as parameter is on it's own, as in:

```
int bar();
int foo(void);
```

In C this means the function `bar` takes an undetermined number of arguments while `foo` does not take any arguments. In C++ both are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

`void` is an **incomplete type** and cannot be used as the parameter of a function(in both C and C++) with the exception that if `void` is the only parameter of that function. This can be seen from the following quoted statements.

##### C++

From [function's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function):

> Parameter list determines the arguments that can be specified when the function is called. It is a comma-separated list of parameter declarations, each of which has the following syntax:
>
> - 5 Indicates that the function takes no parameters, it is the exact synonym for an empty parameter list: `int f(void);` and `int f();` declare the same function. Note that **the type void (possibly cv-qualified) cannot be used in a parameter list otherwise: `int f(void, int);` and `int f(const void);` are errors** (although derived types, such as void* can be used). In a template, only non-dependent void type can be used (a function taking a single parameter of type T does not become a no-parameter function if instantiated with T = void).

Note also that there is a semantic difference(between C++ & C) in case `void` is used as a parameter of a function and is the only parameter as shown in the following example:

```
int func(void);  //declaration of func that takes no parameter and has the return type of void
int foo();     //declaration of foo that takes no parameter and has the return type of void
```

##### C

From [function declaration's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration):

> parameters cannot have type void (but can have type pointer to void). The special parameter list that consists entirely of the keyword void is used to declare functions that take no parameters.
>
> ```
> int f(void); // OK
> int g(void x); // Error
> ```

> **Unlike in C++ and function definitions (since C23), the declarators `f()` and `f(void)` have different meaning**: the declarator f(void) is a new-style (prototype) declarator that declares a function that takes no parameters. The declarator f() is a declarator that declares a function that takes unspecified number of parameters (unless used in a function definition)